# Which method to retrieve path portion of URL in Sitecore?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm writing an extension to the `HTTPRequest` pipeline to redirect incoming requests where Sitecore can find the right item but where the requested URL isn't formed exactly as Sitecore would form it. This is to prevent SEO duplicate content issues.

The portion of the URL I want to examine is the part that will conform to the `LinkManager.GetItemUrl(context.item)` result. In our case we have language embedded in the path, e.g.:

```
www.mysite.com/en-gb/stuff/things
```

So `GetItemUrl` returns `/en-gb/stuff/things`

I can't find the right method, either on the `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs` object, nor on the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` object.

I can get the whole URL or the path minus language embedding. Which object.method will give me `/en-gb/stuff/things`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but it seems like what you're looking for is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` . If not, please explain what you want to achieve with more details.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to have the query string trimmed as well before I did a comparison, but if there isn't a RawUrl minus QueryString method then the answer is yours.

Comment: You can just truncate the RawUrl value from any question mark in the query string.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just hoping to cut away as much string manipulation as possible.

Answer (score 2):

This isnt a direct answer, but it may be useful nonetheless, as Sitecore throws a couple of tricks into the mix when doing what (I think) you're aiming to achieve.

From memory...

The language portion of the URL is removed by the strip language pipeline processor, if (and only if) the linkmanager is set with LanguageEmbedding 'always' or 'asNeeded'. If it is set to 'never' if does nothing to the url in the HttpRequest. This can mess with your path comparison if comparing a stripped path with a prefixed path from LinkManager.

You can add a pipeline step *before* the stripLanguage step which adds the incoming URL as you want it to the dictionary within HttpRequest.

```
public class StoreOriginalRequestUrl : PreprocessRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
    {
        args.Context.Items["OriginalRequestUrl"] = args.Context.Request.RawUrl;
    }
}
```

...you can then pick this up in a later step after the item resolver. I'm presuming this is what you're doing - comparing the request URL with the context item's URL from Linkmanager.

I think you can parse the linkmanager returned Url string as a Uri object and compare the path there. It seems to behave better when fed a fully qualified URL, so perhaps modify the UrlOptions returned from GetDefaultOptions() to provide one.

Paul

Comment: Thanks, some good tips there. There is an OriginalString property on the Request.URl object which ensures you get the original data (though including port number), but it's definitely worth remembering that the various pipelines modify the HttpContext object as it's passed along them, so getting the right position in the pipeline list needs a little thought.

Comment: The StripLanguage pipeline (6.4) overwrites the OriginalString prop. Observed after the ItemResolver, the language is not there. I find this counter-intuitive. @Paul-George, I'm using your suggestion and recording the original requested path before the StripLanguage processor. I didn't find a very convenient object to store it in, but it seems to work. I'm storing the value in the HttpRequest's Browser.Capabilities dictionary where I can later retrieve it after the ItemResolver in the pipeline. Where would you suggest it be stored when you say "to the -->dictionary within HttpRequest<--"?

Comment: @Isubi I've added an example, albeit from memory. You should be able to store on args.Context.Items dictionary within the request.